# How do you close the block from the inside?

Tags: reactjs

I need to close the block inside him. By clicking 'close'. How do I do that? 
Can you help me, please? I'm just a rookie.

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-thunder-bpot3?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Just pass down your handler to the `Block` instance

```
function Block(props){
  return(
    <section>
      <p className="close" onClick={props.handler}>close</p>
    </section> 
  );  
}
```

and in the App.js

```
  <div>
    <p onClick={this.handleClick}>click this for more information</p>
    {this.state.isOpen ? <Block handler={this.handleClick}/> : null}
  </div>
```